# Classification task, result differ when test set distribution differ

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

i'm using a conv net to classify image. Multiclass problem (got 12 class)

My training set is 3500 image, class unbalanace (e.g class A =1200 image, class B = 50 images). I use class weight to fight unbalance, and data augmentation

**edit** data augmentation is with keras function, doing just rotation and flip.  I only augment training set

Since some of my class have really small data, I made a split 60 % training/20% validation/ 20% test set (i.e for class B i got 30 training data/ 10 validation data/10 test data)

Then I made different split, with every time different training/validation and test data
Result are stable => my metric (micro F1 score) doesnt change a lot with different split, and confusion matrix show me that there is no class effect: different split doesnt mean different result for a given class

Now, I apply my model on a set with NO LABEL. Around 10 000 image. 
and result are very poor: when I got 60% precision score for class B on test set, my precision is around 5% for the set with no label

My question:

could it be overfiting? When I stop training model, training loss = 0.3/ training F1 = 95%. Validation loss = 0.7/ validation F1=80%
I dont think so since validation loss doesn't increase (I stop model before it's increase)

What could I investigate to understand why my result are so poor on the new set with 10 000 data (when I says my result, I speak about precision since this is the only one metric I can calculate easily for some classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are overfitting because your model is learning on a small set of class B images which is augmented. Augmentation results in more data but inherently the content of the image remains the same. If your new unlabeled class B images are similar to the training images, then you should not have this problem but if they are different, then you will have this problem. Train your model on augmented images too but validate only on the original images to prevent overfitting and help model generalize better. Look at this [link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/when-using-data-augmentation-is-it-ok-to-validate-only-with-the-original-images).

One other thing you can try is take a small sample from other classes and train a new model without augmentation and then test the images. This will give you some clarification if the model is overfitting on augmented data or not.

You can also try advance augmentation techniques like GAN if you are only doing basic augmentation in Keras. If possible update your question with the augmentation steps.

Comment: Thanks!  I have edited question.  I lose around 5% performance when I don't use data augmentation on test set (set with label)

Comment: What about validation. Data augmentation should only be there for training data, not for validation and test.

Comment: My bad.  I meant: I only augment training set.  With no augmentationI l lose 5% on test set.

Comment: Train your model only on two classes on equal sets and test the prediction. Before we jump into solution, we need to figure out the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I found where the error is coming from. I'm reducing resolution of image from both set but it's lead to error on the set with 10000 unlabeled data.